# == and === operators in php

Tags: php, operators, equality-operator

Let's say I have a variable that will always be a string.

Now take the code below:

```
if($myVar === "teststring")
```

Note: `$myVar` will always be a string, so my questions is

Which is quicker/best, using `===` (indentity) or the `==` (equality)?

Comment: I would use == in that case since you don't really care about the type of $myVar. I'm pretty sure speeds are about the same (it's so trivial that it dosen't matter - even in a mega loop).

Comment: If you decide to use `==`, reversing the condition (`"teststring" == $myVar`) helps catching possible typos (if you miss one of the two equal signs, you're going to change the value of `$myVar` and have an always-true if condition!).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Testing for identity is always faster, because PHP does not have to Type Juggle to evaluate the comparison. However, I'd say the speed difference is in the realms of nanoseconds and totally neglectable.

Related reading:

- [PHP type comparison tables](http://de3.php.net/manual/en/types.comparisons.php)
- [Type Juggling](http://de3.php.net/manual/en/language.types.type-juggling.php)

Comment: +1. Just out of curiosity, I just run a quick test putting a `==` statement and a `===` in a loop so that they got executed 10 million times. There was no real difference between the two. Repeating the test several times `==` was sometimes faster, sometimes slower, but we're really talking about 1 ms difference...

Comment: @nico That would depend if `==` triggered a type conversion or not. You might have tested a case where you were comparing variables of the same type (or a case the equality operator doesn't even attempt conversion).

Answer (score 2):

`===` will be slightly faster, but more importantly, It enforces that `$myVar` *will* be a string so you don't have to worry about the possible effects of it being some other type.

Answer (score 0):

In general when I code, I use == over ===, however, using the identity is more precise, and also, slightly faster (difference is minimal).

The difference between the two is likely irrelevant for whatever you need.

Comment: IMHO `==` should be avoided when you can since it takes more human effort to correctly read how type juggling effects the statement (especially in PHP). With `===` it's either an exact match or it's not.

Comment: I agree, and after looking into it more - im gunna modify my statement.